# create two sets of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create two sets of a dataframe by removing two rows (ignoring the NA values). The two rows should be stored in a new dataframe and should be removed from the original dataframe. Then the next two rows (without overlap) and the on:

```
# Dataframe
x       y       ID
39.54   116.39  ID1
38.27   117.26  ID2
28.27   119.55  ID3
27.34   119.43  ID4
NA  NA  ID5
30.17   109.28  ID6
9.083333333 39.08333333 ID7
NA  NA  ID8
NA  NA  ID9
NA  NA  ID10

### First set
# Training
x   y   ID
28.27   119.55  ID3
27.34   119.43  ID4
NA  NA  ID5
30.17   109.28  ID6
9.083333333 39.08333333 ID7
NA  NA  ID8
NA  NA  ID9
NA  NA  ID10

#Validation
x   y   ID
39.54   116.39  ID1
38.27   117.26  ID2

### Second set
# Training
x   y   ID
39.54   116.39  ID1
38.27   117.26  ID2
NA  NA  ID5
30.17   109.28  ID6
9.083333333 39.08333333 ID7
NA  NA  ID8
NA  NA  ID9
NA  NA  ID10

#Validation
x   y   ID
28.27   119.55  ID3
27.34   119.43  ID4


### Third set
# Training
x   y   ID
39.54   116.39  ID1
38.27   117.26  ID2
28.27   119.55  ID3
27.34   119.43  ID4
NA  NA  ID5
NA  NA  ID8
NA  NA  ID9
NA  NA  ID10

#Validation
x   y   ID
30.17   109.28  ID6
9.083333333 39.08333333 ID7
```

How can I split the dataframes to extract always two rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove missing values by[`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) first and extract `index`, then loop by subindices and remove from original `DataFrame` for `train` and select for `validation`:

```
#if necessary replace strings `NA` to `NaN`s
df = df.replace('NA', np.nan)

idx = df.dropna(subset=['x','y']).index

for x in range(0, len(idx), 2):
    train = df.drop(idx[x:x+2])
    validation = df.loc[idx[x:x+2]]
    print (train)
    print (validation)
```

---

```
           x           y    ID
2  28.270000  119.550000   ID3
3  27.340000  119.430000   ID4
4        NaN         NaN   ID5
5  30.170000  109.280000   ID6
6   9.083333   39.083333   ID7
7        NaN         NaN   ID8
8        NaN         NaN   ID9
9        NaN         NaN  ID10
       x       y   ID
0  39.54  116.39  ID1
1  38.27  117.26  ID2
```

---

```
           x           y    ID
0  39.540000  116.390000   ID1
1  38.270000  117.260000   ID2
4        NaN         NaN   ID5
5  30.170000  109.280000   ID6
6   9.083333   39.083333   ID7
7        NaN         NaN   ID8
8        NaN         NaN   ID9
9        NaN         NaN  ID10
       x       y   ID
2  28.27  119.55  ID3
3  27.34  119.43  ID4
```

---

```
       x       y    ID
0  39.54  116.39   ID1
1  38.27  117.26   ID2
2  28.27  119.55   ID3
3  27.34  119.43   ID4
4    NaN     NaN   ID5
7    NaN     NaN   ID8
8    NaN     NaN   ID9
9    NaN     NaN  ID10
           x           y   ID
5  30.170000  109.280000  ID6
6   9.083333   39.083333  ID7
```

Comment: Thanks, but it stores NA in the valdiation set which should be not the case.

Comment: I am using Python 3.8 and Pandas 2.0.1

Comment: @honeymoon - Hmm, so `NA` are strings, not `NaN`s missing values, so `print(df.dropna(subset=['x','y']))` not working (not remove rows with missing values)?

Comment: @honeymoon - If yes, can you replace them to missing values before my solution by `df = df.replace('NA', np.nan)` ?

Comment: jezrael How to buy you a coffee?

Comment: @honeymoon - Just created, thank you - https://www.buymeacoffee.com/jezrael